# fundamental theorem of elimination theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have trouble completing the proof of the fundamental theorem of elimination theory in Ravi Vakil.   I understand everything he says but i dont see how to translate the Zariski-closedness of the condition on the coefficients mentioned in the last paragraph into the Zariski-closedness of the set of prime ideals $\frak p$ in the first paragraph.  I mean clearly the coefficients of  the images of the $f_i$'s in $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})[x_0,...,x_n
]$ depend on the $\frak p$, but they take values in different fields as $\frak p$ varies... i have no idea...
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can write the determinant conditions that you get in terms of the $f_i$ and then ask for which $\mathfrak p$ does this vanish when you go to $k( \mathfrak p)$. This is the same as asking the polynomials in the $f_i$ that you get from the determinant conditions to belong to $\mathfrak p$. Either way you see it, this defines a closed set.

Comment: @RijulSaini I see now. Thank you!